# Is there a way to display the total count of rows in a separate row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

| City_Id | City |
| --- | --- |
| 41 | Athena |
| 39 | Beijing |
| 35 | London |
| 30 | Rio de Janeiro |
| 28 | Salt Lake City |
| 18 | Sochi |
| 7 | Sydney |
| 4 | Torino |

is there a way to display another row in the bottom that will display the total count of rows?

| City_Id | City |
| --- | --- |
| 41 | Athena |
| 39 | Beijing |
| 35 | London |
| 30 | Rio de Janeiro |
| 28 | Salt Lake City |
| 18 | Sochi |
| 7 | Sydney |
| 4 | Torino |
| Total | 8 |

Comment: *Yes*, but `City_Id` is clearly an `int` and so you would have to `CONVERT` the value of it (and convert the `COUNT` to a `varchar` too). Both seem like bad ideas. This seems like something for the presentation layer.

Comment: ...if you're executing this query from something like Java, PHP, or Python, the total number of records in the result set should be readily available to you there.

Comment: This should probably be tackled at the presentation layer rather than at the database layer.

Comment: @Larnu, you're definitely right about the presentation layer, but i wanted to know if there's a way to do that in an SQL-query.

Comment: You can, but that doesn't mean you should. Like I said,it should be done in the presentation layer; doing it in the SQL layer is the wrong tool for the job. It's like using a Hammer on a screw when you have a perfectly suitable screwdriver within reach. The screw will go in, but you'll likely do more damage as it does (in your case, the damage is to the integrity of the data).

Comment: use `group by grouping sets` or use a union to add on the additional record.  But as larnu stated, neither of these will fit/work as a datatype issue is presented; and you have other places to get the info.

Comment: @Aby_g what if there are 3 columns you want to display? What if there are a lot of rows? Applications almost always execute a count query separately. When using paging they use that result to calculate pages and return the total and number of pages to the client

Comment: @Aby_g as for returning numbers as text, that's just evil and will lead to problems almost immediately. Your code now will have to guess the real types of the strings it sees, not knowing if a value in `City_ID` is in reality an integer or not

Comment: Have you looked into using `GROUP BY ROLLUP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can actually use `GROUPING SETS` for this.** This avoids having to scan the table twice.

However you still have the data-type mismatch problem. You could solve it by casting, but it's probably easier to just swap the columns around

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(City) = 0 THEN City ELSE 'Total' END AS City,
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(City_Id) = 0 THEN City_Id ELSE COUNT(*) END AS City_Id
FROM Table1
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (City_Id, City),
    ()
)
ORDER BY GROUPING(City_Id);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fe28b/2)

What this does is generate separate result-sets, unioned together. You can differentiate between a grouped row and a non-grouped row using the `GROUPING` function.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with most of the other comments that acquiring a result set count would be more appropriate from the application code (which usually has a mechanism specifically for this purpose).

However...

If you must have a TSQL solution for your question, an option is to return the count in a separate column. This is different than returning it in a separate row, of course. There are pros & cons with each approach.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Cities;

CREATE TABLE #Cities (
    City_Id INT,
    City VARCHAR(128)
);

INSERT INTO #Cities
VALUES
    (41,    'Athena'),
    (39,    'Beijing'),
    (35,    'London'),
    (30,    'Rio de Janeiro'),
    (28,    'Salt Lake City'),
    (18,    'Sochi'),
    (7 ,    'Sydney'),
    (4 ,    'Torino');

SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Total
FROM #Cities;

--Count is properly reflected based on WHERE clause.
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Total
FROM #Cities
WHERE City LIKE 'S%';

--Be careful with this one--the COUNT(*) may not be what you expected.
SELECT TOP(4) *, COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Total
FROM #Cities;
```

**NOTE:** be aware that this approach may not scale (perform) well for large result sets. Be sure to do some testing!

Answer (score 0):

As you know already, it should be done in the presentation layer. But if you just want to know if there is any way, then I would suggest to use `UNION ALL`

```
select cast(City_Id as varchar(10)) City_Id, City from Table1
union all
select 'Total' as City_Id, cast(count(*) as varchar(14)) from Table1
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d83e68fff6f5076b6be9be0e79791b34) is the sql fiddle

Comment: I would suggest it a poor assumption to *assume* `City_Id` is a `varchar`. It is clearly numerical. Also, why `UNION`? What duplicate rows are you trying to remove here?